# Efficiently/pythonically calculating new Dataframe rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to Pandas, and slightly new to Python as well (but not development in general). I've got a chunk of code that works, but it feels like I'm missing out on the Pandas/Python way of doing something, and would love some feedback.

In short, I'm doing calculations over a fixed period of time (say 60 months) where I apply a bunch of different financial calculations to generate various debits and credits. In this example I'm calculating gross incomes. I have models that represent the `Income`s, and want to create Dataframes with the corresponding data that I can eventually sum together for final answers.

Full code for experimentation is available at https://repl.it/repls/BlissfulShabbyColdfusion and repeated here:

```
### Income Models: ###
start_date   end_date     amount   yearly_raise
2019-01-01   2025-01-01   100.0    0.03
2020-01-01   2022-01-01   200.0    0.

### Base DataFrame: ###
            YearOffset 
2019-01-01           0 
2020-01-01           1 
2021-01-01           2 
2022-01-01           3 
2023-01-01           4
```

Then the code is as follows:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Income:
  def __init__(self, start, end, amount, yearly_raise):
    self.start = start
    self.end = end
    self.amount = amount
    self.yearly_raise = yearly_raise

# Two sample income models
incomes = [
  Income(datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), datetime.date(2025, 1, 1), 100, 0.03),
  Income(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), datetime.date(2022, 1, 1), 200, 0.)
]

# Create dataframe with index of the next five years
dates = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=5, freq='YS')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(dates)), index=dates, columns=['YearOffset'])

def calculate_monthly_income(row):
  """Given a dataframe row, add up all incomes applicable to that row/month"""
  value = 0.
  for income in incomes:
    # Filter on overlapping date ranges first
    if pd.Timestamp(income.start) > row.name or pd.Timestamp(income.end) < row.name:
      continue

    value += row['GrossIncome'] + income.amount * (1 + income.yearly_raise) ** row['YearOffset']

  return value

# Initialize a GrossIncome column and do the math
df['GrossIncome'] = 0.
df['GrossIncome'] = df.apply(calculate_monthly_income, axis=1)
```

And the after, which yields the correct results:

```
### After Calculations: ###
            YearOffset  GrossIncome
2019-01-01           0   100.000000
2020-01-01           1   303.000000
2021-01-01           2   306.090000
2022-01-01           3   309.272700
2023-01-01           4   112.550881
```

**Thoughts:**

- I'm using `apply()` to iterate through the rows and assigning the result back into the dataframe. This works and beats using a for loop, but seems like there's probably a better way to do this.
- I'm still using a `for ... in` to iterate through multiple `Incomes`
- The filtering by applicable date range also seems like I should probably be using some built-in Pandas thing like `mask`, but I'm unsure of where to start looking.

There's a lot here, I know, but if there's some good feedback on the current approach or recommendations for better approaches, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. There is a lot of context missing in that code, for example `incomes`, `pd` and other values. As your repl.it snippet is quite short, I recommend you to include the complete snippet, including the `import`s.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Zeta. I went ahead and pulled all the code in from the repl to provide context.

Comment: Did you resolve this?